# How do I install and configure NTP on CentOS 7 from source? (include/ntp_crypt.h errors)

Tags: centos, networking, openssl, ntp

I unpacked the .tar.gz file for the newest NTP. I installed the gcc compiler and libcap devel. I ran the ./configure command with various flags and options. I ran make check and found an error. The exit status is 2. Only 0 is without errors. In the output I see this:

```
../../include/ntp_crypt.h:23:2: error: #error AUTOKEY should be defined only if OPENSSL is.  #error AUTOKEY should be defined only if OPENSSL is.

../../include/ntp_crypt.h:24:14: error: expect '=', ',' ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ' token invalidsyntax: AUTOKEY should be defined only if OPENSSL is.

../../include/ntp_crypto.h:27:25: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory #include "openssl/evp.h"
```

How do I fix this error so I can use the make install command to get NTP installed?

Comment: Is there really a big problem with the `ntp` packages that CentOS provides? You are missing openssl development libraries.

Comment: I am using the newest ntp package (released within the past 10 days) because of the really big exploit of NTP.  The ntp (dot org) website has on their front page that users are strongly recommended to take immediation action because of the DDOS attack.  The vulnerability is so big, I have no idea why more people aren't rushing to fix it.  The default CentOS one is too old, isn't it?  Where can I find a list of the openssl development libraries that I need?

Comment: Distributions backport security fixes to older versions of software. The fixes have been [uploaded to RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016:0063) and likely already exist in CentOS.